# scrollViewDidScroll called when launched before scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am using

- https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

and it has it's `containerview` which is a `scrollview` that the children `viewController` will be displayed in ...

am trying to change a view's height when user scroll it .. am doing this:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.homeimg.image = UIImage(named: "smalllogo")
    self.imageheight.constant = 116
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations:{ self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
}
```

this perfectly do what i want as i need .. the problem is the `containerview` is scrolled as soon as it launch .. so this is called as soon as launched even before scrolling or touching anything ...

how to solve this? and do the changes only when scrolled or touched?

Comment: You shouldn’t set the constraint in scrollViewDidScroll if you want to update but you should set it in viewDidLayout

Comment: @zombie how? i want to make the changes only when i scroll?

Comment: Why don't you use Delegate methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
var viewAppeard = false

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    viewAppeard = true
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if viewAppeard {

        self.homeimg.image = UIImage(named: "smalllogo")
        self.imageheight.constant = 116
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations:{ self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})

    }

}
```

Comment: now nothing happen even if i scrolled ... maybe this is because am actually scrolling the child inside the containerview not the containerview itself?

Comment: just check your viewDidAppear gets called or not and it set the viewAppeard flag or not ?

Comment: @vivekDas its called and viewAppeard = true

Comment: okay , just implement the scrollView delegate method 'scrollViewWillBeginDragging' in that you just set viewAppeard = true not in viewDidAppear and check, remove the code viewAppeard = true from viewDidAppear